# How can i update the TFS workarea in local machine only updated checked-ins files\folders

Tags: tfs

For TFS, how can I update my workarea of new check-ins file or folder only. When I'm giving the command `tf get WORKAREA LOCATION`, it is showing `All the files/folders are up to date.`  But all new check-ins files/folders are not up to date, actually.  When I'm running the command `tf get WORKAREA LOCATION /recursive /force` the get is showing:

```
Replacing AtomicsTest.java
Replacing BadLegacyDefaults
Replacing BadLegacyDefaults
Replacing BasicXMLClassTest
Replacing BigDecimalSubclas
Replacing EncodingTest.java
Replacing FileTest.java
Replacing HierarchicalField
Replacing HierarchicalField
Replacing InnerClassXMLTest
Replacing PrimitiveClassesT
Replacing PrimitivesTest.ja
Replacing PutFieldGetFieldT
Replacing ReadResolveTest.j
Replacing ReferenceTest.jav
Replacing SelfReferentialTe
Replacing SerializableObjec
Replacing SerializationTest
Replacing StandardSerialize
Replacing StringTest.java
Replacing TCDictionaryXMLTe
Replacing TransientAndStati
Replacing XMLTestSuite.java
```

Which means updating each files and folder which is also not new which takes more time to update. So is there ant way to update only new files/folders only.

Comment: Why do you believe that there are new files that you're not getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running tf get from a directory in your workspace will update all **out-of-date** sources. Passing the /force parameter will cause *all* files to be retrieved rather than just those that are out of date.

If you only want files beneath a particular particular path, you can specify an **itemspec**. The command line would look like this:

```
tf get $/project/folder/subfolder /recursive
```

Comment: but i want only new files\folder only not all. pls help me out

Comment: tf get will only get new/updated files and folders. I've edited my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: when i m running the cmd like `tf get $/project/folder/subfolder /recursive` it updating my old file also like we have one build.xml file in which i already change some target for build but after running above command it replacing that build.xml file every time.